# Continuous network call from intent service in background

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have created an Intent Service and I am calling it from NotificationChecker.java which extends Broadcast receiver.What I want to do is in background at a fixed interval of time I want to download text from a URL and toast that string.In intent service I am reading data from the URL but It is not receiving any data.Here is my Sample Code.

```
package com.jamiahamdard.hammad.noticeboard;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

String finalJson="ygf";
private Handler handler;
Context context;
public MyIntentService() {
    super("MyIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
URL url=new URL("http://sig.ieeejamiahamdard.org/notice_board/notices.txt");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String line = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        finalJson = buffer.toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), finalJson,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }


  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  onHandleIntent(intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
 }
```

}

and for Broadcast Receiver

```
package com.jamiahamdard.hammad.noticeboard;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class NotificationChecker extends BroadcastReceiver {


SharedPreferences student;
String finalJson;
Context mycontext;
Intent intent;
public NotificationChecker() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String studentData=intent.getExtras().getString("student");


    context.startService(new Intent(context,MyIntentService.class));
}
}
```

Comment: Did you declare your receiver in your manifest?

Comment: actually my intent service is working fine but when I make network  call like when I read text from URL it does not toast anything

Comment: <receiver android:name=".NotificationChecker">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: I have declared both intent service and receiver.

Comment: did you check for any exception? toast the error in catch block once. check if it toasts the error.

Comment: Yes it is throwing exception.so the toast is not executing because it jumps to catch block .But why it is throwing exception?